# why these real-mode code works in virtual machine but not working on my real machine?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, real-mode, mbr

I'm trying to write assemble code into mbr to use BIOS ISRs. I write the following code to the mbr, expecting the chars "ABCD" to be printed on the screen:

```
mov ah,0x0e
mov bp,0x8000
mov sp,bp

push 'A' 
push 'B'
push 'C'
push 'D'

mov al, [0x7ffe]
int 0x10

mov al, [0x7ffc]
int 0x10

mov al, [0x7ffa]
int 0x10

mov al, [0x7ff8]
int 0x10

; infinite loop
jmp $

; padding 0s and set the  magic number to make it bootable
times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0     
dw 0xaa55
```

these code works well on the bochs or qemu simulator, but when I write to my real disk and use it to boot, nothing is printed. I've tested to directly set the %al register to chars , and it print well. I'm using a AMD PhenomII 955 processor, anything I 've done wrong ?

Comment: Initialize the segment registers with something like `xor ax, ax` `mov ss, ax` `mov ds, ax`. The instruction `mov al, [...]` uses `ds` while `push ...` uses `ss`. Make sure they are equal.

Comment: @MargaretBloom That works ! thank you ! please post it as an answer, then I can mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize the segment registers with something like

```
xor ax, ax       ;Initialize seg regs with 0
mov ss, ax 
mov ds, ax
```

The instruction `mov al, [...]` uses `ds` while `push ...` uses `ss`.
Make sure they are equal.

---

I didn't mention it, but as [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39465804/why-these-real-mode-code-works-in-virtual-machine-but-not-working-on-my-real-mac/39470035?noredirect=1#comment66277609_39470035) rightfully noted, you have to be careful when updating `SS`.
The pair `SS:SP` must be updated *atomically* with respect to interrupts, otherwise an interrupt triggered midway through the initialization will use a `SS:SP` pair not fully valid.

The easiest way to do it is by updating `sp` *just after* the initialization of `ss`

```
mov bp, 0x8000
mov ss, ax
mov sp, bp
```

beacuse the CPU inhibits the interrupts for the whole instruction after `mov ss, ...`.
Otherwise you can explicitly wrap the initialization code in a `cli` `sti` pair.

Comment: Since the OP doesn't disable interrupts explicitly (in theory the BIOS could leave them on prior to jumping into the boot sector code), do you think it is wise to update _SS_ without altering _SP_ as well? I'd probably just make it explicit that if updating _SS:SP_ that you update _SS_ and then _SP_ right after (Update to _SS_ and interrupts are off until the end of the following instruction) or just use _CLI_ to to turn them off for the duration of the startup code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch You are absolutely right. I'm updating the answer.